# Why the user_id is getting NIL here when I am creating the notes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my appointments controller. Here, why the user_id is getting NIL here? Although I have permited the user_id. 
Associations: Appointment has_many Notes, User has_many Notes, Notes belongs_to User, Notes belongs_to Appointment

```
def new
    @appointment = Appointment.new
    @note = @appointment.notes.build({user_id: current_user.id})
end

def create
    @appointment = Appointment.new(appointments_params)
    @appointment.patient_id = current_user.id

    if @appointment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Appointment saved!"
      redirect_to authenticated_root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

private
def appointments_params
  params.require(:appointment).permit(:date, :doctor_id, :patient_id, :image, :starting_time, notes_attributes: [:id, :description, :user_id, :_destroy])
end
```

Comment: do you get user_id in params ?

Comment: No, how to get that here

Comment: you can pass user_id in hidden_field_tag

Comment: Can you please add the association in your question ?

Comment: Like this:
<%= f.fields_for :notes do |note_field| %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
                <%= note_field.label :Note %><br>
                <%= note_field.text_area :description, placeholder: "Leave note here.", required: true %><br>
            <% end %>

Comment: Yes. right. check in log that are you getting user_id in notes or not

Comment: Can you please tell how to check that?

Comment: (1.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO `appointments` (`date`, `doctor_id`, `image`, `patient_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2018-02-13', 2, 'Screenshot_from_2018-01-16_14_15_57.png', 18, '2018-02-12 03:49:50', '2018-02-12 03:49:50')
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO `notes` (`description`, `appointment_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('nsdjsabdjsd', 196, '2018-02-12 03:49:50', '2018-02-12 03:49:50')
   (41.3ms)  COMMIT                                                                                           See the notes, user_id is not getting passed

Comment: Did you write  `accepts_nested_attributes_for :notes` in your appointment model ?

Comment: Yes, I did that

Comment: you can check the logs in your terminal where your server is running . can you just tell me how the params is passing in your log when you hit submit button ?

Comment: Now I have fixed that issue, thanks

Comment: Glad to know that :)